# Getting "abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult" duplication error

Tags: java, android

Getting this error in my Android app "Tactic Defence".

> [2014-11-07 17:24:20 - appcompat_v7] res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png:0: error: Resource entry abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult is already defined.
>   [2014-11-07 17:24:20 - appcompat_v7] res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9 (1).png:0: Originally defined here.
>   [2014-11-07 17:24:20 - appcompat_v7]
>   [2014-11-07 17:24:21 - TacticalDefence] res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png:0: error: Resource entry abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult is already defined.
>   [2014-11-07 17:24:21 - TacticalDefence] res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9 (1).png:0: Originally defined here.
>   [2014-11-07 17:24:21 - TacticalDefence]

It appears in the console whenever I try to debug, also, TacticalDefence and appcompat_v7 projects give an error:

> Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but exporting the proyect to Android Studio and developing there solved the problem for me.